# SQLMAP como introducir usuario y password de apache

Tags: python, mysql, http

estoy usando SQLMAP para para la url que quiero comprobar necesita acceder mediante usuario y password de apache.

Normalmente utilizo desde otros sitios la siguiente llamada

```
https://usuario1:mipass@misitio.org/
```

Pero desde SQLMAP me da error

```
py sqlmap.py -u "https://usuario1:mipass@misitio.org/id=1"
```

Error:
[CRITICAL] invalid target URL

¿Como le puedo indicar el usuario y password para acceder ?

Salu2

Answer (score 0):

Hasta dónde sé, no hay manera que puedas proveer el usuario y contraseña de la manera que intentas hacerlo o vía parámetros especializados a SQLMap.

Una posible solución es indicar los headers necesarios para realizar la autenticación vía el parámetro `--headers`.

Ya que la autenticación es de Apache, esto debiera traducirse en:

```
py sqlmap.py -u "https://misitio.org/id=1" --headers="Authorization: Basic dXN1YXJpbzE6bWlwYXNz"
```

La cadena `dXN1YXJpbzE6bWlwYXNz` es `usuario1:mipass` codificados en base64 usando el encoding de tu request, en este caso he utilizado ISO-8859-1, pero dado que no tiene caracteres fuera del ASCII normal, UTF-8 daría el mismo resultado.